Issue with Scaling TikZ Picture in Beamer (Basic Code Used From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727125/278762, thanks to @JLeonV.)
First, thanks to @JLeonV. providing me the code https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727125/278762. Below is the output using \documentclass{standalone}:

Problem: When I switch from \documentclass{standalone} to \documentclass{beamer}, the TikZ drawing becomes too large to fit within a frame. See the screenshot below:

To solve this, I decided to scale it down by using scale=0.4. However, the scaling does not work as expected. See the blue arrows (1) and (2) on the screenshot below:

Can anyone help me figure out why scaling doesn't work properly?
Code:
\documentclass{beamer}


%% packages
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta,backgrounds}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Serif Font

%% colors
\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6];
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}[1]{
    \def\initAngleRotorCupI{2.7}
    \def\initAngleRotorCupII{-0.9}
    %
    \pgfmathsetmacro\PosAngleI{\initAngleRotorCupI+#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\PosAngleII{\initAngleRotorCupII+#1}
    %
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\PosAngleI]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleRed] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{1.8}{1.6}{.1};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\PosAngleII]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleGreen] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{1.8}{1.6}{0.1};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) -- (90+#1:5.3);
}

%another way to define draw objets
\def\PoleShoeCol[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][size #5 deg x #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,transform shape]
        \fill[#4]
        (-#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25)
        -| (0:#3+#6)
        |- (0+#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25);
    \end{scope}
}

\def\PoleShoeFeet[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][arc #5 toes #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2+#5/#6*0.25,transform shape]
        \fill[#4,rounded corners=2.5]
        (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:#3+1)
        arc (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:-#5/2:#3+1)
        \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \j using {\k+1}]in {1,...,#6}{
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*1:#3+0.75) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.99:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.50:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.49:#3+0.75)
        }
        -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*#6-#5/#6*0.49:#3+1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\Steppermotor}[2]{
    \draw[thin](0,-10)--(0,10);
    \draw[thin](-10,0)--(10,0);
    \AxiallyMagnetizedRotor{#1}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=0}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/PoleRed/A{/}/100,
            45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            90/PoleGreen/A/100/,
            135/gray!70!black/B{/}/0,
            180/PoleRed/A{/}/100,
            180+45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            270/PoleGreen/A/100,
            270+45/gray!70!black/B{/}/0%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
    }{}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=45}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/gray!70!black/A{/}/0,
            45/PoleRed/B/100,
            90/gray!70!black/A/0,
            135/PoleGreen/B{/}/100,
            180/gray!70!black/A{/}/0,
            180+45/PoleRed/B/100,
            270/gray!70!black/A/0,
            270+45/PoleGreen/B{/}/100%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
        
    }{}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=90}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            90/PoleRed/A/100/,
            135/gray!70!black/B{/}/0,
            180/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            180+45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            270/PoleRed/A/100,
            270+45/gray!70!black/B{/}/0%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
        
    }{}
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!90] (0,0) circle (10) (0,0) circle (10.5);
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!70!black] (45/2+45*0:8.5) \foreach \k in {1,...,7} {-- (45/2+45*\k:8.5)}
        -- cycle (0,0) circle (10) \foreach  \r in {1,...,4}{(45+90*\r:9) circle (0.75)};
        \foreach \m in {0,...,8}{\PoleShoeCol[At 0,0][angle 45*\m][radious 5.2][color gray!70!black][size 50 deg x 3]}
    \end{scope}
    
    \filldraw[even odd rule,gray] (0,0) circle (0.5) (0,0) circle (1);
}



\begin{document}
    
    % Iterate over the angles and create a new frame for each iteration
    \foreach \StepAngle/\b in {0/0,1.8/45,3.6/90} {
        \begin{frame}{Stepper Motor Rotor at $\StepAngle^\circ$}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
                \Steppermotor{\StepAngle}{\b}; % Call your Steppermotor function for each angle
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    }
    
\end{document}


scale scales only coordinates. If you want to scale everything (but no line thickness and arrows, by design) you should use scale=0.4, transform shape. This is the safest way of scaling a tikzpicture. If you want to scale everything, your approach is ok.

See https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.7 for the details

ok thx a lot Rmano

As you are using beamer: \begin{frame}[shrink] \frametitle{Stepper Motor Rotor at $\StepAngle^\circ$} \begin{tikzpicture} \Steppermotor{\StepAngle}{\b};  \end{tikzpicture} \end{frame}

I was able to figure this out on my own. I used \scalebox{0.4}{...} instead of scale=0.4, and it works perfectly.
Code:
\documentclass{beamer}

%% packages
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta,backgrounds}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Serif Font

%% colors
\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6];
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}[1]{
    \def\initAngleRotorCupI{2.7}
    \def\initAngleRotorCupII{-0.9}
    %
    \pgfmathsetmacro\PosAngleI{\initAngleRotorCupI+#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\PosAngleII{\initAngleRotorCupII+#1}
    %
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\PosAngleI]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleRed] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{1.8}{1.6}{.1};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\PosAngleII]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleGreen] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{1.8}{1.6}{0.1};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) -- (90+#1:5.3);
}

%another way to define draw objets
\def\PoleShoeCol[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][size #5 deg x #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,transform shape]
        \fill[#4]
        (-#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25)
        -| (0:#3+#6)
        |- (0+#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25);
    \end{scope}
}

\def\PoleShoeFeet[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][arc #5 toes #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2+#5/#6*0.25,transform shape]
        \fill[#4,rounded corners=2.5]
        (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:#3+1)
        arc (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:-#5/2:#3+1)
        \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \j using {\k+1}]in {1,...,#6}{
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*1:#3+0.75) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.99:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.50:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.49:#3+0.75)
        }
        -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*#6-#5/#6*0.49:#3+1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\Steppermotor}[2]{
    \draw[thin](0,-10)--(0,10);
    \draw[thin](-10,0)--(10,0);
    \AxiallyMagnetizedRotor{#1}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=0}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/PoleRed/A{/}/100,
            45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            90/PoleGreen/A/100/,
            135/gray!70!black/B{/}/0,
            180/PoleRed/A{/}/100,
            180+45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            270/PoleGreen/A/100,
            270+45/gray!70!black/B{/}/0%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
    }{}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=45}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/gray!70!black/A{/}/0,
            45/PoleRed/B/100,
            90/gray!70!black/A/0,
            135/PoleGreen/B{/}/100,
            180/gray!70!black/A{/}/0,
            180+45/PoleRed/B/100,
            270/gray!70!black/A/0,
            270+45/PoleGreen/B{/}/100%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
        
    }{}
    
    \ifthenelse{#2=90}{
        
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            90/PoleRed/A/100/,
            135/gray!70!black/B{/}/0,
            180/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            180+45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            270/PoleRed/A/100,
            270+45/gray!70!black/B{/}/0%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white,scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
        
    }{}
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!90] (0,0) circle (10) (0,0) circle (10.5);
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!70!black] (45/2+45*0:8.5) \foreach \k in {1,...,7} {-- (45/2+45*\k:8.5)}
        -- cycle (0,0) circle (10) \foreach  \r in {1,...,4}{(45+90*\r:9) circle (0.75)};
        \foreach \m in {0,...,8}{\PoleShoeCol[At 0,0][angle 45*\m][radious 5.2][color gray!70!black][size 50 deg x 3]}
    \end{scope}
    
    \filldraw[even odd rule,gray] (0,0) circle (0.5) (0,0) circle (1);
}



\begin{document}
    
    % Iterate over the angles and create a new frame for each iteration
    \foreach \StepAngle/\b in {0/0,1.8/45,3.6/90} {
        \begin{frame}{Stepper Motor Rotor at $\StepAngle^\circ$}
            \scalebox{0.4}{\begin{tikzpicture}
                \Steppermotor{\StepAngle}{\b}; % Call your Steppermotor function for each angle
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{frame}
    }
    
\end{document}

Output:

